# If a system has a symmetry, must the non-degenerate Ground state of it be the one-dimensional irreducible representation of the symmetry group?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, group-representations, greens-functions, correlation-functions

I am now solving a problem about the properties of retarded Green functions when the system has a certain symmetry. If the Ground state is nondegenerate, must the Ground state be of the one-dimensional irreducible representation of the symmetry group? Because if it is not the basis of the one-dimensional irreducible representation, then there should be another state belonging to the same representation which has the same eigenenergy.  Then it can't be degenerate. Am I right?

By the way, what properties should a correlation function $G_{\hat{A}\hat{B}}(\boldsymbol{r})$ have when the system has a certain symmetry, for example, rotation symmetry. Does the change of operator $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ under symmetry operation matter? not just the vector $\boldsymbol{r}$.

You can just answer the first question.

Comment: yes, the ground state is the singlet--that's what non-degenerate means, no? The symmetry generators thus annihilate it, so the group operation leaves it alone.